# c#. Взаимодействие с Exchange Server

Tags: c#, сервер, exchange

Необходимо написать небольшое приложение, которое работает с почтовыми ящиками в `Exchange Server` - Создает/изменяет записи в календаре, синхронизирует адресную книгу с внешними данными. Приложение пишется на хорошо известном мне [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) но с `Exchange Server` дела не имел, а необходимо быстрое вхождение в тему.

Какие существуют способы взаимодействия с `Exchange Server`? Только лишь `API EWS` про которые я тоже только что узнал?

А если приложение будет устанавливаться на машине, где работает `Exchange Server`? Существуют ли тогда возможность более прямого обращения к нему?

Answer (score 1):

[Вот тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt674770.aspx) "[Choosing the right Exchange technology](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj162981.aspx)" может быть интересно, но судя по всему да, EWS это главный стандарт, независимо от того где ваш клиент работает. Вашу боль немного облегчат семплы кода которые там есть.

Answer (score 1):

Наиболее правильным выбором будет работа с Exchange через EWS. В NuGet есть пакет `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices`, используйте его. API довольно простое, плюс данная библиотека предоставляет обёртку над SOAP, сильно упрощая работу и позволяя использовать готовые классы.

Есть официальная документация, [доступная на сайте MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633710), а также удобная утилита [EWSEditor](https://ewseditor.codeplex.com/), позволяющая посмотреть и частично отредактировать структуру метаданных в том виде, в котором их видно через EWS.
Кстати, исходники библиотеки [доступны на GitHub](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api).